# How to put Array data in CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I chose CharField(validators=...) for alternative to `CommaSeparatedInteger` field to store array into the field.

The Http request has `selectedColorsIds` body field and I want to put the data into `color` field of `PostDetail` model

```
...
"selectedColorIds": Array [
    112,
    110,
  ],
...
```

models.py

```
from django.core.validators import validate_comma_separated_integer_list

class PostDetail(models.Model):
    ...
    color = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

views.py :> But I'm getting this error when I try to put the array into the field. `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'color' error`

```
color = self.request.data.get('selectedColorIds') # [112, 110]
detail_instance = PostDetail.objects.get_or_create(post=post_instance)
detail_instance.color = color  <<- error here
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I store array in the Django model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[**`get_or_create()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)* method return a tuple of (object, created), where object is the created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

```
detail_instance, created = PostDetail.objects.get_or_create(post=post_instance)
```